# Trouble with unicode

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sqlite database with a list of file locations.

```
file
"D:\Accounts\Silo\161130_paid\BRW0080929A5C36_001952.pdf"
...
```

I am trying to get python to rename all the files in this column.

My issue is that when I try to use the string python is seeing the "\161" part as a character and converting it into a "q".

I realise that it is possible to escape this with a backslash, however I have no idea how to do that on a large number of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a raw string, by prefixing the `r` flag.

```
>>> '\161'
'q'
>>> r'\161'
'\\161'
```

See [string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) from the documentation for more information.

Comment: sweet - just another really basic question. is it possible to prefix a variable in this way?